# How to install uuid-ossp postgresql extension in arch Linux

Tags: postgresql, archlinux

I need to install uuid-ossp postgresql extension on arch linux. I have postgresql-9.5. On ubuntu its easy to do via `sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib` but how to do this in arch Linux?

Comment: Similar to https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/290793/248393

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `postgresql` package doesn't provide `ossp-uuid`-feature. You have to enable it via `./configure` before compiling. So you have two ways to get this feature:

1. compile postgresql yourself with  `--with-ossp-uuid`-flag and install it via `make install`. (I don't recommend this)
2. Download the postgresql package specifications via the tool `asp`. You can install it with `sudo pacman -Syu asp` and then do: `asp checkout postgresql`. Then you need to modify the `PKGBUILD` and insert the `--with-ossp-uuid`-flag inside of the `build()`-function. Then you can simply build the package and install it with `makepkg -si`. It is possible that you need additional dependencies. I haven't tested it, but it should work this way.